# Office365 Account to sign into a third-party website

Tags: office365

My requirement is just like [office365 Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632408/office365-authentication). 
I want to do these steps:

1. Click a button in my webpage to open a new window(named "o365signIn") that linked to https://login.microsoftonline.com/.
2. Use email and password to sign in Office365(in "o365signIn" window) successfully.
3. Get authorization code from window "o365signIn".
4. Close window "o365signIn" and take authorization code to my webpage and use it to do other things.

Any ideas? or any clues to lead me to the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create an Office 365 app, and add that to your website for authentication.

For more info you can check out this link, http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/authorization/app_authorization, that explains how you actually do the implementation.

Just be sure to only ask for the permissions you actually need for the website, in this case it seems like you only need the basic permissions, to get the users info and see if the user is authenticated.